# Gradle and Sonar - connection refused error

Tags: build, gradle, sonarqube

I have configured gradle and sonar plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'sonar'

// sonar settings - gradle-1.0-milestone-3 2  - check new sonar plugin for milestone 5 release
        sonar {
            server { 
                Url = "http://myserver:9000"
            }
            database {

            url="jdbc:mysql://myserver:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username="usrname"
            password="pwd"
            }

        }
```

- I can connect to sonar using web browser.
- I can connect to mySQL database using simple java test program.
- I have copied mysqlconnector.jar file into GRADLE_HOME/lib

when I run

gradle -debug sonarAnalyze

I am getting:

```
09:42:25.074 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 53 more
09:42:25.074 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: **Connection refused: connect**
09:42:25.074 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.remoteContent(Bootstrapper.java:123)
09:42:25.075 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:156)
09:42:25.075 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 65 more
09:42:25.075 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:42:25.075 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
09:42:25.076 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] **BUILD FAILED**
09:42:25.076 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
09:42:25.076 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 5.59 secs
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`server.url` in your code snippet is misspelt; it needs to be a lower case `u`. Other than that, it could be a wrong URL or wrong network configuration. Or maybe you are using a version of the Sonar server that isn't compatible with the Sonar client library that ships with Gradle 1.0-milestone-3.

By the way, Gradle 1.0-milestone-3 is really old (18 months or so), and a lot has changed since then. I recommend to try with 1.0.

Comment: Thank you. It was upper case in the property url.